# Get rid of these log messages in node.js

Tags: node.js, express, error-logging

How could I suppress these log messages:

[image: GET /stylesheets/style.css 500 451ms - 1.08kb Get /scripts/script.js 200 985ms - 91b]

Or atleast get them to not change my console's background and foreground colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**0) remove the logger middleware**

Comment out `app.use(express.logger())` from your code...or make it conditional on your node environment settings so you get stuff in dev but not in production.

**1) Use a different logger**

You can search around for this in npm and you'll find things like [express-winston](https://github.com/heapsource/express-winston).

**2) Write your own logger**

If what you need is simple, here's the example that's straight from the docs:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next){
  console.log('%s %s', req.method, req.url);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `express.logger`

```
app.set('view engine', 'jade')
app.configure(function() {
 // ̶a̶p̶p̶.̶u̶s̶e̶(̶e̶x̶p̶r̶e̶s̶s̶.̶l̶o̶g̶g̶e̶r̶(̶'̶d̶e̶v̶'̶)̶)̶;
    app.use(stylus.middleware({
```